# How do you properly stop execution of an express.js endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a middleware error handler that is working great but next(err) and return and return next(err) seems to not stop execution when dealing with promises. What is the proper way to stop execution of my code when an error is found?

For reference: err is a standard Error class in this case.

I don't think you need the code in userProvider.fetchFriends to help with this but if that's wrong please let me know.

```
  const uid = req.query.steamUserId;

  //Use the userProvider to get steam friend data
  const friendData = await userProvider.fetchFriends(uid)
  .catch(err => {
    return next(err); //Does not stop execution. Why? just next(err) doesn't either.
  });

  //Putting this after every catch works but seems very stupid. How do I avoid this?
  if(res.writableEnded) 
    return;

  ...Other code that runs but causes errors
}
```

Comment: Why mix async/await _and_ .then/.catch? Given that you're awaiting the promise, use try/catch - returning in a callback is _never_ the same is returning in the outer function.

Comment: Put the await inside a "normal" try-catch

Answer (score -1):

You've got two problems here.

First: `next()` is explicitly continuing to the next middleware or endpoint.

To finish dealing with the request, send a response.

```
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
    if (something(req)) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.status(500).json({ ok: false, msg: "some error message" });
    }
}
```

---

Second: You need to watch your asynchronous logic carefully.

You can't:

1. trigger something asynchronous
2. send a response
3. send a different response when the asynchronous function is complete

You can only send one response to a request.

Either:

- Don't call `next` or `res.something` in the `catch` block and just log the error internally **or**
- Don't call `next` or `res.something` *outside* the promise handling and move it to a `then` handler instead (you might want to switch to using `async`/`await` to make your logic easier to follow)

Answer (score -3):

The issue was that I was mixing async/await with .then/.catch. Needed to use try/catch.

ty @jonsharpe

```
export const getSteamFriends = async (req, res, next) => {
  try{
    const uid = req.query.steamUserId;

    //Use the userProvider to get steam friend data
    const friendData = await userProvider.fetchFriends(uid);
  
    //more code in the middle
  } catch(e) {
    return next(e);
  }
};
```